# How to pass success state back to component without updating store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a simple form in react-redux meant to try to add a user to the database, if it is successful, display a success message. However I am not sure of the best approach to do this. I have the following:

```
onSubmit = e => {
  ...
  const newUser = { user object here }
  this.props.registerUser(newUser);
}
```

in `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)`:

```
if (nextProps.success === true) {
    this.setState({ success: nextProps.success });
}
```

in the `render()`:
*Meant to display a success component giving further information. There is also a conditional check to hide the form if success is true*

```
{ this.state.success === true && 
  (<SuccessComponent name={this.state.name} />)
}
```

in `mapStateToProps`:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  success: state.success
});
```

in my `action`:

```
.then(res => {
  dispatch({
    type: REGISTRATION_SUCCESS,
    payload: true
  });
})
```

in the `reducer`:

```
const initialState = false;

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REGISTRATION_SUCCESS:
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

in `combineReducers`:

```
export default combineReducers({
  success: successReducer
});
```

In this, I am basically using the response from the server to dispatch a success prop to the component, update the state, which forces react to render and go through the conditional statement again, hiding the form and displaying the new success block.

However, when I go into redux dev tools, I see that the state from the store is now `true`, and remains so should users navigate away. Is there a better way to go about this objective? I find that maybe this should be isolated to component state itself, but not sure how to do it since the action and hence the server response is through redux.

Comment: I'll advice you to dispatch a request action, maybe **REGISTRATION_REQUEST**, before dispatching the **REGISTRATION_SUCCESS**. The request action should set the success field to false.

Comment: I'll try come back to the answer later - but check out this question of mine - and links from it: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/382230/redux-loading-success-error-pattern-when-using-redux-saga - I call this the PENDING/LOADING/SUCCESS/FAILURE pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redux is a state machine, not a message bus, so try to make your state values represent the current state of the application, not to send one-time messages. Those can by the return value of the action creator. Success or failure can simply be the existence/lack of an error from the action creator.

If you actually do want to store the user info, you can derive your "was successful" state by virtue of having a registered user, and clear out any existing registered user on component mount.

```
// actions.js
export const clearRegisteredUser = () => ({
  type: SET_REGISTERED_USER,
  payload: null,
})

export const register = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
  // async functions implicitly return a promise, but
  // you could return it at the end if you use the .then syntax
  const registeredUser = await api.registerUser(userData)
  dispatch({
    type: SET_REGISTERED_USER,
    payload: registeredUser,
  })
}

// reducer.js
const initialState = { registeredUser: null }
const reducer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch(type) {
    case SET_REGISTERED_USER: {
      return {
        ...state,
        registeredUser: payload,
      }
    }
    default: {
      return state
    }
  }
}

// TestComponent.js
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    registrationError: null,
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.clearRegistered()
  }

  handleSubmit = async (formData) => {
    try {
      this.props.register(formData)
    } catch(error) {
      // doesn't really change application state, only
      // temporary form state, so local state is fine
      this.setState({ registrationError: error.message })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { registrationError } = this.state
    const { registeredUser } = this.props

    if (registrationError) {
      return <FancyError>{registrationError}</FancyError>
    } else if (registeredUser) {
      return <SuccessComponent name={this.props.registeredUser.name} />
    } else {
      return <UserForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
    }
  }
}
```

If you really don't need the user info after you register, you can just perform the api call directly and leave Redux out of it.

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    registered: false,
    registrationError: null,
  }

  handleSubmit = async (formData) => {
    try {
      await api.registerUser(formData)
      this.setState({ registered: true })
    } catch(error) {
      this.setState({ registrationError: error.message })
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { registered, registrationError } = this.state

    if (registrationError) {
      return <FancyError>{registrationError}</FancyError>
    } else if (registered) {
      return <SuccessComponent name={this.props.registeredUser.name} />
    } else {
      return <UserForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, avoid keeping copies of redux state in your component state whenever possible. It can easily lead to sync issues. Here's a good article on avoiding derived state: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html

Answer (score 1):

First off, I don't think that you should be using your Redux store for saving what is essentially local state.

If it was me I would probably try to make the api call directly from the component and then write to the redux store if it is successful. That way you could avoid having your derived state in the component.

That said, if you want to do it this way I would suggest componentWillUnmount. That would allow you have another Redux call that would turn your registration boolean back to false when you leave the page.

Comment: Whether an API call succeeded or not, is not local state.